# selenium webdriverio click on android/iPhone/iPad broswers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have a test that passes on all devices except my mobile ones and it seems to be failing at `click()`. I am using selenium webdriver, here's a code snippet:

```
it('Expand when clicked', function (done: any) {
    client
      .waitForVisible('[pane-state-value="focused"] [pane-state-value="focused"] .smartimage-container-small', 15000)
      .click('[pane-state-value="focused"] [pane-state-value="focused"] .smartimage-container-small')
      .waitForVisible('body > .smartimage-container-large [fullscreen-image]', 15000)
      .getElementSize('body > .smartimage-container-large [fullscreen-image]').then(function (fullscreenSize: any) {
      client.getElementSize('body').then(function (bodySize: any) {
        assert.equal(bodySize.width, fullscreenSize.width, 'fullscreen doesn\'t use full width');
        assert.equal(bodySize.height, fullscreenSize.height, 'fullscreen doesn\'t use full height');
      })
        .call(done);
    });
  });
```

I came across an article, https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/the-selenium-click-command, that indicates that the click command is not supported on the mobiles devices but I was told that these tests were previously passing so I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something more obvious. I have tried calling `doubleClick()` and adding a pause before the click. The click function executes but nothing happens on the emulated mobile device. I have also plugged my phone and checked dev tools and have ensured that the selector exists.

Comment: Have you tried any of these suggestions?  https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/181

Comment: Yes, I got buttonClick is not a function.